# Java stored procedure SHA256 with RSA Signature not available

Tags: java, oracle, procedure, sha256

I have a problem with java stored procedure on oracle database version "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.3.0 64bit Production".

I need to use sha256withRsa to sign some datas. In this case I have used java stored procedure. The same source code work on Netbeans ide with JDK1.5 or JDK1.7 (tryed to change).

When I execute the same code on database side i get:

ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256WithRSAEncryption Signature not available

This line of code is the cause:

Signature podpis = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");

How to solve this problem?

Java on database side is: JDK 1.5.0_10

Comment: SHA256withRSA is not available in java 1.5. 
[Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html)

Comment: Are you sure? Why then it works with Nebeans with java 1.5 I have specified in project properties? (my java version when i use it in netbeans is: Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0-b64)

Comment: You can check this. Look on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this class in netbeans and in plsql. To view output in plsql execute.
`set serveroutput on;`
`dbms_java.set_output(20000);` And you are looking for Signature.SHA256withRSA.

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Enumeration;

/**
 *
 * @author alukasiewicz
 */
public class TestSignature {

   public static void print() throws Exception {
    try {
        Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
      for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(p[i]);
          for (Enumeration e = p[i].keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
              System.out.println("\t" + e.nextElement());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I have done it on oracle database.. the result from java stored procedure returned 7 providers which are (SUN version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1.6, SunJCE version 1.6, SunJGSS version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5,  XMLDSig version 1.0)

Comment: Thank you Aradiusz, On oracle 11g with java 1.6 it works fine with SHA256withRSA.. On oracle 11g version 10.1.3.0 there is java 1.5 and SHA256withRSA is not present... We will upgrade our database with higher patch which has java 1.6...